# How to modify or custom sessionId in spring session project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

My project use Spring Boot and Spring Session,now i want to modify or custom sessionId before session data persistence in redis,How should I do?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to go through the docs Spring Session works well with spring boot

Docs :http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/

It will tell you that coupling the custom implementation with `@EnableSpringHttpSession` support allow to easily reuse existing Spring Session configuration facilities and infrastructure.

The tenth chapter [10. Custom SessionRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#custom-sessionrepository) will tell what you want.

Comment: this resource is now a dead link btw

Comment: Here's the new link https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/api.html#custom-sessionrepository

Answer (score 1):

Spring Session currently does not provide a way to specify custom session id generation strategy, so unfortunately the only way to do this at the moment is indeed to provide a custom `SessionRepository` implementation.

We do however have an [existing ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/11) in our issue tracker for this, so please vote if you'd like to see this prioritized.

Comment: But I use AOP realize it.