# Creating custom session cookie for Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, session-cookies

We are using custom session cookie through **application.properies** in our application as follows:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=<custom session cookie name>
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
```

As of now, this cookie with associated UUID is getting generated through Spring boot framework I guess. But I would like to override the UUID generation and creation of this custom cookie.

I am not getting an idea how will I do this. Could anyone please give any pointer/code reference regarding the same? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer implements ServletContextInitializer {


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        SessionCookieConfig sessionCookieConfig =
            servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig();
        ...
    }
```

Here in the above code snippet, I realize I can override the following attributes associated with session cookie:

**MaxAge**, **Name**, **Comment**, **Domain**, **Path**, **Secure**, **HttpOnly** etc.

But I cannot figure out how would I override the UUID associated with the existing session cookie.

Comment: Please check this out https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-custom-cookie.html

Comment: Thanks @SimonMartinelli for your response. Yeah, I saw this. Actually I am wondering if there is any way to implement a custom generator for UUID for this session cookie.

Comment: What's wrong with the UUID? And how would you like to generate it?

Comment: Actually @SimonMartinelli, this  UUID is getting generated in Spring framework and  it is not recommended to use UUID as per https://neilmadden.blog/2018/08/30/moving-away-from-uuids/. So I am thinking of overriding this with one custom UUID generator.

But I am not getting any clue how would I integrate this custom UUID generator in existing Spring boot application.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It would be of great help if you can give some pointers/reference to integrate custom UUID generator for this custom session cookie.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353967/how-to-modify-or-custom-sessionid-in-spring-session-project

Comment: As far as I can see is Tomcat generating the Session id and as far i can see it uses SecureRandom. Have a look https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/catalina/util/SessionIdGeneratorBase.java

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have gone through the links. But still I am not able to figure out how would I inject a custom UUID generator. I have updated the OP accordingly.

Comment: I think you can't because this is not code from Spring but from Tomcat. And I assume that the generated ID is secure because milliions of applications use Tomcat

Comment: Yeah, @SimonMartinelli I understand generated ID in Tomcat is completely secure. I am looking for a way to port this as a class and inject it in order to override existing UUID of an existing session cookie.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do and why?