# How to instantiate org.springframework.session.MapSession in my Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I am working on managing sessions for a Spring boot application. In this context, I would like to instantiate `MapSession` object myself in the application with `id` generated by myself, so that I can override its current instantiation of `MapSession` object as follows which has potential risk involved (https://neilmadden.blog/2018/08/30/moving-away-from-uuids/):

```
public MapSession() {
    this(generateId());
  }

private static String generateId() {
   return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
 }
```

Is it possible to do this from the application ? If yes, could anyone please give some pointers/code reference for the same?  Thanks.

**EDIT**

In this regard, I have gone through this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1148 and related links: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/11 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/pull/204.

It seems as of now, there is no way to override this, I mean I cannot change the session id generated as the above code snippet. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

I have gone through related SO post: [How to modify or custom sessionId in spring session project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353967/how-to-modify-or-custom-sessionid-in-spring-session-project), but not getting any clear idea regarding how to implement a custom session repository.

I have tried implementing a custom session repository as follows:

```
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class CustomSessionRepository implements SessionRepository<MapSession> {

  private Integer defaultMaxInactiveInterval;
  private  Map<String, Session> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public CustomSessionRepository() {
      this.sessions = sessions;
  }

  public void setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(int defaultMaxInactiveInterval) {
    this.defaultMaxInactiveInterval = defaultMaxInactiveInterval;
  }

  public void save(MapSession session) {
    if (!session.getId().equals(session.getOriginalId())) {
      this.sessions.remove(session.getOriginalId());
    }

    this.sessions.put(session.getId(), new MapSession(session));
  }

  public MapSession findById(String id) {
    Session saved = (Session)this.sessions.get(id);
    if (saved == null) {
      return null;
    } else if (saved.isExpired()) {
      this.deleteById(saved.getId());
      return null;
    } else {
      return new MapSession(saved);
    }
  }

  public void deleteById(String id) {
    this.sessions.remove(id);
  }

  public MapSession createSession() {
    MapSession result = new MapSession(myCustomId());
    if (this.defaultMaxInactiveInterval != null) {
      result.setMaxInactiveInterval(Duration.ofSeconds((long)this.defaultMaxInactiveInterval));
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

But here I have missed something because now the session is not getting persisted to Redis as expected.

Comment: @xenoterracide, do you have any idea regarding this, as I saw few of your posts regarding this, so thought of checking.

Comment: What does this do? public MapSession() {  this(generateId()); } What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code, end goal... Spring boot will most likely have that functionality..

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far? And what is the outcome of your steps? Your question appears to be a little vague.

Comment: @zee Actually as of now session id is getting generated with the code snippet as I posted in OP. This code is part of Spring session framework. 

The session id generated in this way has potential risk involved as I mentioned in the OP. 

So I am trying to override this generated session-id before it gets persisted to redis.

I did not find concrete way so far to do this.

Comment: @sbsatter As mentioned in the linked SO post, I am trying to implement SessionRepositiory interface so that I can overwrite the session-id before it gets persisted to redis. But I cannot find any such Custom implementation done as part of the Spring boot application.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1406

Comment: Hi @zee, thanks. I have gone through this github link. But still, I am not able to find any concrete approach to implement a proper custom session repository that would fulfil my use case.

Comment: Did you try overriding the createSession method? This would allow overriding the session id.

Comment: @RobWinch, thanks for your response. I tried as mentioned in the OP. But could not make it work. Maybe, I am missing something.

Comment: @Joy any luck with this? Having the same requirement.

Comment: Hi, @ChinthakaDharmasiri I actually took a clone of the Spring Session repo, did appropriate change, and made a jar out of this. Then I made a change in pom.xml to make use of this jar.